# Length of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

when creating tables(and columns inside it) using MySQL gui clients there is a field called 'length' of a column. What exactly does it mean. Isn't range for a datatype (say)int fixed. Does length relate to the range of column value in anyway? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't range for a datatype (say)int fixed.

No - but MySQL has [some predefined sizes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) for integers.

> Does length relate to the range of column value in anyway

Yes, it sets a limit on the size of what you put in there - but don't assume its directly equivalent to the number of characters you key in (see previous link, also, this one on [multibyte characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748965/what-is-a-multibyte-character-set))

Answer (score 1):

yes, indeed. E.g. a varchar(255) field can hold up to 255 characters.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html for all datatypes