# What is the difference between mblen and strlen?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, strlen

What is the difference between mblen and strlen?

Is today multi-byte character encoding used in Windows, Linux or Mac OS? Is multi-byte character encoding same as fixed-width character encoding in Windows?

Comment: I think you mean mbslen iso mblen?

Comment: @Noctum: mblen exists in cstdlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen` takes the length of a `const char *`, and assumes that one `char` takes one byte, so it counts the chars until a null terminator ('\0') has been encountered, whereas `mblen` takes a pointer also of type `const char *`, but this points to the first byte of the [multi byte character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding).

For more info on what are multi-bye characters, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748965/what-is-a-multibyte-character-set) question.