# How does C handle a multi-byte character that includes a null character?

Tags: c

Section 5.2.1.2.1 of the C11 standard states:

> A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character
>   independent of shift state. **Such a byte shall not occur as part of any
>   other multibyte character**.

Which, I think, makes it clear that a multibyte character can not have any of its bytes zero. If so, the below example should not work (because the characters contain zero bytes); but it does.

```
char16_t wc= u'\u1200';
char16_t wcs[] = u'\u1200\u1300';
printf("%#x, %#x, %#x\n", wc, wcs[0], wcs[1]);
```

Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a single int there, not a multibyte char. Multibyte char probably refers to stuff like UTF-8 and Shift-JIS.

Comment: Wide characters are different from multi-byte characters.  Wide characters may have null bytes but only one null (zero) wide character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the term *multibyte character* (which is, possibly, an ambiguous term). For example, from [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjaks/index.html):

> The term “multibyte character” is defined by ISO C to denote a byte
>   sequence that encodes an ideogram, no matter what encoding scheme is
>   employed. All multibyte characters are members of the “extended
>   character set.” A regular single-byte character is just a special case
>   of a multibyte character. The only requirement placed on the encoding
>   is that no multibyte character can use a null character as part of its
>   encoding.

Thus, the condition you quoted refers to character strings that are arrays of ***single byte*** elements, but which can contain characters that require more than one of those single-char elements for their representation.

The `char16_t` type you use is a **wide character**, in which *all* representable characters are encoded as 2-byte values - even 'simple' stuff like an `ASCII` 'A', which would be `0x0041`.

EDIT: I realize that what I have written above is confusing! However, while searching for a basis for some clarification, I came across this Stack Overflow post: [What is a multibyte character set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/748965/10871073) I can't really improve on the answers given there, so maybe it could be used as a 'duplicate'.

Comment: thanks, can you please explain/simplify that text you just quoted? I read it and it's really confusing.

Comment: @user3124390 see edit and the SO link given there. (As I've already posted an answer, I'll leave it for others to VTC this as a duplicate, should they see fit to do so!)

Comment: See C11 [§3 Terms, definitions, and symbols](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.7) on 'character', 'multibyte character' and 'wide character'.  Though, in all honesty, those definitions are not dreadfully helpful.